# On which Stack Exchange site can I ask this blogger related question?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, blog

I read **[this vague question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355239/blogger-usage-questions)** which is very similar to the one you are reading now, but it is much vague and so it has received vague comments and answers, so it's of no help.

Now comes **[my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49237802/how-to-configure-a-dynamic-blogger-template-neomag-template-to-be-exact-to-u)** that I have already asked on the main Stack Overflow site.

[image: Question deleted because it is too broad]

[Deleted XML link](http://pasted.co/27a31609)

And I have realised it's just a garbage there, while nobody has yet downvoted it, but **it doesn't seem to fit in the rules** so I need to move the question to a Stack Exchange site where it fits.

Comment: OK, you need to start searching....

Comment: @MartinJames I am not sure if webapps and webmasters fit my problem. If you think any of them are the right place, please explain

Comment: If you know the question is not on-topic here on Stack Overflow, please delete the question.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan but deleting that question would make the link in this question obsolete too. Any cure for that?

Comment: Make a screenshot for <10k user, everyone else can see deleted questions.

Comment: We've got the screenshot right there for those of us below 10k, as BDL mentions.

Comment: Instead of asking "which site is appropriate" on meta.SO, why don't you find out if webapps is appropriate for you on meta.webapps and webapps/help? That way (most likely) you'll receive more relevant answers.

Comment: @user2027289 original motive of this meta question is obsolete now, original question has been deleted. Now it just stands as example for noobs who might search a similar question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably try [webapps.stackexchange.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com). Normal use of web applications such as blogger are on-topic on that site.

Read what's [on-topic](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for that site. I don't have personal experience with that site, so I don't have a clue about how it will be received. Your question seems too broad to me, but norms might be different here.

Comment: i read whats on-topic before asking, but i am not sure about requesting support over it and yes even I think my question is too broad :(

Comment: my mistake, i hadnt searched with the "blogger" keyword on webapp earlier. I will take time and break my questions down to smaller parts and then ask. will take time but give results. thx again

Comment: If you repost the question on any other SE site: Make sure to read the help center very carefully. At least on SO your question is off-topic since it doesn't provide the template XML in the question itself.

Comment: @BDL I will remember that, and my question provided the template xml, it was there in blue coloured **link**.

Comment: @Subham: I guess you missed my point: On SO you have to have everything relevant to reproduce the problem **in the question itself**. Links to other source may only be used as additional material. The reason is that questions get rendered useless if the link dies.

Comment: @BDL well I think pasted.co will not delete my xml going by their t&c but maybe.. I started using pasted.co since I saw reputed stackoverflow users using it so I thought its links were reliable. But the NeoMagz link and the site link of my blog can easily change, now thats my mistake. sry again

Comment: @Subham Link rot is not the only reason for keeping the content here on SO. Many people access SO from work, and many companies prevent their users from accessing code- (and potentially any text-) sharing sites. If they have access to SO only, they can still make sense of your question.